Why can I not import from `npm`'s global libraries?
My shell is zsh (which I recently switched to and am still learning) and I am trying to create the following alias:
alias bip39="echo \"import('bip39').then((bip) => bip.generateMnemonic()).then((mne) => console.info(mne))\" | NODE_PATH=\"$(npm root -g):$NODE_PATH\" node"

When I run exa $(npm root -g), I get:
@ceramicnetwork  @composedb  @web3-storage  bip39  corepack  npm
Running echo "Node: $(node -v) & NPM: $(npm -v)" returns "Node: v20.15.1 & NPM: 10.7.0".
Trying the command I want to alias, echo "import('bip39').then((bip) => bip.generateMnemonic()).then((mne) => console.info(mne))" | NODE_PATH="$(npm root -g):" node, I get:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'bip39' imported from /home/dys/[stdin]
Did you mean to import "bip39/src/index.js"?

Trying to import the suggested path (which I'd really prefer not to do) doesn't work either.
Alternatively, how do you generate your bip39 seeds under Debian? 
